Failed to fetch item description: ClientException: XMLHttpRequest error., uri=ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR from flutter app hosted on a web server
I have a Flutter web app that runs on my web server and fetches data from a Node.js API, also hosted on the same server. In the Flutter web app, when you input an item number, it is supposed to communicate with the Node.js API and return the corresponding item description to be displayed. However, when my app attempts to check with the API on the web server, I encounter this error in the Chrome developer log:

Failed to fetch item description: ClientException: XMLHttpRequest
error., uri=ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

I've attempted the following solutions:
Added  to my index.html file in the head area. (Without this tag, I receive the following error:

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://web.cpsk12.org/surplus/' was
loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint
'http://web.cpsk12.org:3000/surplusItems?CPSNumber=no%20'. This
content should also be served over HTTPS. Implemented CORS in my API
code.

It's worth noting that this setup works when I run the web app locally on my computer, but not when it's hosted on the web server.
here is my web api code
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const sql = require('mssql');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

// Database configuration
const config = {
    user: 'db username',
    password: 'db password',
    server: 'db server', // Your database server
    database: 'db name ',
    options: {
        enableArithAbort: true,
        encrypt: true, // Use encryption for this connection
        trustServerCertificate: true // Trust the self-signed certificate
    },
};

// Middleware
app.use(cors()); // Setup CORS for all domains
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // Parse JSON bodies

// Endpoint to get an item description by CPSNumber
app.get('/surplusItems', async (req, res) => {
    const { CPSNumber } = req.query;
    if (!CPSNumber) {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: "CPSNumber parameter is missing" });
    }

    try {
        await sql.connect(config);
        const result = await sql.query`SELECT Description FROM SurplusItemsNew WHERE CPSNumber = ${CPSNumber}`;
        sql.close();

        if (result.recordset.length === 0) {
            return res.status(404).json({ error: "No item found with the given CPSNumber" });
        }

        res.json(result.recordset[0]);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error occurred:", error);
        sql.close();
        return res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal server error" });
    }
});

// Endpoint to submit multiple surplus items
app.post('/submitSurplusItems', async (req, res) => {
    const items = req.body.items;
    if (!items) {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: "No items provided" });
    }

    try {
        await sql.connect(config);
        const transaction = new sql.Transaction();
        await transaction.begin();
        const request = new sql.Request(transaction);

        for (const item of items) {
            await request.query`INSERT INTO SurplusItemsNew (BuildingName, CPSNumber, Description, ReasonDescription, SurplusStatus) VALUES (${item.school}, ${item.cpsNumber}, ${item.itemDescription}, ${item.selectedReason}, 1)`;
        }

        await transaction.commit();
        res.json({ success: true, message: "Items successfully inserted." });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error occurred:", error);
        res.status(500).json({ success: false, error: "Internal server error" });
    }
});

// Start the server
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
and here is my flutter page code
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:surplus/form_data.dart';
import 'package:surplus/summary.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class FormPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FormPageState createState() => _FormPageState();
}

class _FormPageState extends State<FormPage> {
  List<FormData> forms = [];
  String? _selectedSchool;
final List<String> _schools = [
  'Alpha Hart Lewis Elementary',
  'Battle High School',
  'Benton Elementary',
  'Beulah Ralph Elementary',
  'Blue Ridge Elementary',
  'Business Office',
  'CORE-Boys and Girls Town',
  'CORE-Quest',
  'Cedar Ridge Elementary',
  'Center for Early Learning North',
  'Columbia Area Career Center',
  'Derby Ridge Elementary',
  'Douglass High Adult Basic Ed',
  'Douglass High School',
  'Early Childhood Discovery Cntr',
  'Early Childhood Special Ed',
  'Eliot Battle Elementary',
  'Facilities & Construction Srv',
  'Fairview Elementary',
  'Field Building',
  'Gentry Middle School',
  'Gifted Center',
  'Grant Elementary',
  'Hickman High School',
  'Jefferson Middle School',
  'John Warner Middle School',
  'Juvenile Justice Center',
  'Lange Middle School',
  'Locust Street Expressive Arts Elementary',
  'Mail Check',
  'Midway Heights Elementary',
  'Mill Creek Elementary',
  'Moving On Together',
  'New Haven Elementary',
  'Nutrition Services',
  'Oakland Middle School',
  'Park Avenue Head Start',
  'Parkade Elementary',
  'Paxton-Keeley Elementary',
  'Rainforest School',
  'Ridgeway Elementary',
  'Rock Bridge Elementary',
  'Rock Bridge High School',
  'Rosetta Avenue Learning Center',
  'Russell Blvd Elementary',
  'Shepard Blvd Elementary',
  'Smithton Middle School',
  'Two Mile Prairie Elementary',
  'West Blvd Elementary',
  'West Middle School',
];


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    forms.add(FormData());
  }

  void addNewForm() {
    setState(() {
      forms.add(FormData());
    });
  }

void reviewData(BuildContext context) async {
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => SummaryPage(
        formData: forms.where((element) => element.cpsNumber.isNotEmpty).toList(),
        school: _selectedSchool ?? "",
      ),
    ),
  );
}


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Surplus Asset Disposal Form'),
          centerTitle: true,
      foregroundColor: Colors.white, backgroundColor: Color(0xFF005570), // Set text color to white

        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
                value: _selectedSchool,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Select School',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
                onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    _selectedSchool = newValue;
                  });
                },
                items: _schools.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: value,
                    child: Text(value),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: forms.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => MyCustomForm(
                  formData: forms[index],
                  onCpsNumberTyped: addNewForm,
                  onDataUpdated: (data) {
                    setState(() => forms[index] = data);
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () => reviewData(context),
                child: Text('REVIEW'),
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            foregroundColor: Colors.white, backgroundColor: Color(0xFF005570), // Set text color to white

            ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}



class MyCustomForm extends StatefulWidget {
  final FormData formData;
  final VoidCallback onCpsNumberTyped;
  final Function(FormData) onDataUpdated;

  MyCustomForm({required this.formData, required this.onCpsNumberTyped, required this.onDataUpdated});

  @override
  _MyCustomFormState createState() => _MyCustomFormState();
}

class _MyCustomFormState extends State<MyCustomForm> {
  final TextEditingController _cpsNumberController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _itemDescriptionController = TextEditingController();
  String? selectedReason;
  bool _isFirstInput = true;

final List<String> _reasonsForSurplus = [
  'No Longer Used',
  'Burned Out',
  'Broken',
  'Extinction',
  'Obsolete',
];


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _cpsNumberController.text = widget.formData.cpsNumber;
    _itemDescriptionController.text = widget.formData.itemDescription;
    selectedReason = widget.formData.selectedReason;
    _cpsNumberController.addListener(() {
      final cpsNumber = _cpsNumberController.text;
      if (cpsNumber.isNotEmpty && _isFirstInput) {
        _fetchItemDescription(cpsNumber);
        widget.onCpsNumberTyped();
        _isFirstInput = false; // Prevents continuous addition of forms
      }
      widget.onDataUpdated(widget.formData.copyWith(cpsNumber: cpsNumber));
    });
    _itemDescriptionController.addListener(() {
      widget.onDataUpdated(widget.formData.copyWith(itemDescription: _itemDescriptionController.text));
    });
  }

void _fetchItemDescription(String cpsNumber) async {
  // Update the URL to match the new API endpoint.
  // Assuming your server is running locally and accessible from your Flutter app,
  // you might need to replace 'localhost' with your local IP address when running on a real device.
  //final url = Uri.parse('http://10.250.250.101:3000/surplusItems?CPSNumber=$cpsNumber');
  final url = Uri.parse('http://web.cpsk12.org:3000/surplusItems?CPSNumber=$cpsNumber');

  try {
    final response = await http.get(url);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final data = json.decode(response.body);
      if (data != null && data['Description'] != null) {
        setState(() {
          _itemDescriptionController.text = data['Description'];
          widget.onDataUpdated(widget.formData.copyWith(itemDescription: data['Description']));
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          _itemDescriptionController.text = 'Description not found';
          widget.onDataUpdated(widget.formData.copyWith(itemDescription: 'Description not found'));
        });
      }
    } else {
      print('Server error: ${response.statusCode}');
      // It's a good practice to handle HTTP errors gracefully.
      setState(() {
        _itemDescriptionController.text = 'Error fetching description';
        widget.onDataUpdated(widget.formData.copyWith(itemDescription: 'Error fetching description'));
      });
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print('Failed to fetch item description: $e');
    setState(() {
      _itemDescriptionController.text = 'Failed to connect';
      widget.onDataUpdated(widget.formData.copyWith(itemDescription: 'Failed to connect'));
    });
  }
}



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: Card(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(
                controller: _cpsNumberController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'CPS Number',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
                onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
                  // Trigger fetchItemDescription when Enter key is pressed
                  _fetchItemDescription(value);
                },
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 24.0),
              TextFormField(
                controller: _itemDescriptionController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Item Description',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
                maxLines: null,
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 24.0),
              DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
                value: selectedReason,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Reason for Surplus',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
                onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedReason = newValue;
                    widget.onDataUpdated(widget.formData.copyWith(selectedReason: newValue));
                  });
                },
                items: _reasonsForSurplus.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: value,
                    child: Text(value),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _cpsNumberController.dispose();
    _itemDescriptionController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

thanks in advance

The problem is that you are hosting the app at https://web.c... but serving your API at http://web.c... Move one or other to the same scheme - and preferably the same port. It's easiest to have whatever serves your API to serve your static HTML etc for your Flutter app.

thank you so much for the reply I am a little confused on your comment. what do you mean by Move one or other to the same scheme? sorry to ask such a noob question but can you please explain further? thank you in advance!!!

Could you google scheme? Scheme = http or https in this context.
